# How can I disable "There is an available update" popup in Visual Studio Code / Codium?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, popup

How can I disable "There is an available update" popup in Visual Studio Code?

This updates are never mattering much - definitely not enough to interrupt work.

I anyway update everything as Linux packages, so there is no reason at all to do anything manually.

How can I stop this distracting popups?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set `update.mode` to `none`.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112041#issuecomment-740506061

For VSCodium on Linux it is in `~/.config/VSCodium/User/config.json`